# Combination/Permutation Problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm having trouble understanding this combo/perm problem. The answer is supposed to be 12. Can someone please explain how they got it?

You need to put your reindeer, Prancer, Quentin, Rudy, and Jebediah, in a single-file line to pull your sleigh. However, Rudy and Prancer are best friends, so you have to put them next to each other, or they won't fly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to solve the problem without the "best friend" condition? What if you consider Rudy and Prancer as conjoined twins so that you effectively have three reindeer?

Comment: if anyone has tips on solving combo/perm problems in general i'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will just refer to them by their first letter.

But we basically just consider "RP" as a reindeer. So how many ways are there of ordering RP, Q, J? 3 choices for RP, 2 for Q and 1 for J giving us a total of 6. But the ordering "RP-- "is equivalent to ordering "PR--" so you'd just double your first quantity giving you $$6\cdot 2=12.$$

Comment: thank you! I think it also helped me to see it visually by writing half the combos down. if you have any tips on solving combo/perm problems in general i'd greatly appreciate it!